# What are the port i can use to send email in java?

Tags: port, jakarta-mail

I am developing a email sender in `Java`. I need to know which is the port that we are using in `javaMail.jar`?

And what are the other ports I can use ?

Answer (score 3):

**Common EMAIL ports:**

```
SMTP                      port 25 or 2525 or 587
Secure SMTP (SSL / TLS)   port 465 or 25 or 587, 2526 (Elastic Email)
POP3                      port 110
IMAP                      port 143
IMAP SSL (IMAPS)          port 993
```

Take a [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) for further info

Comment: Thanks a lot.If i create a application using one of this port, can i use it in another pc